# how to make django comment model field Site not required

Tags: python, django, django-comments

I'm using django-threadedcomments from ericflo on github.  This app simply extends the native django comments framework.  I am running into the same issue with both frameworks.  I continue to get an error relating to mysql that site_id cannot be null.  I have no use for the Site field in my comments.  I tried to extend the Comment model with my own making site both blank and null but I am still getting the same error.  What is the proper way to override that requirement?  Thanks

I tried:

```
class Comment(Comment):
    site=models.ForeignKey(Site,null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: where is your error coming from? Can you please post a traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it easier to just define one Site object. `django-threadedcomments` is not the only extension which requires that.

Comment: I like this approach, it seems more efficient than always calling Site.objects.get_current() everytime a new comment is added.  Where does this one site reside?  Should it be in settings.py, or can you use a dummy site_id integer in settings.py?  Or perhaps extending the save method with a subclassed Comment model that assigns an integer to site_id is the cleanest?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to change this without monkey-patching the current model, but it shouldn't be a big deal setting the `site` field to `Site.objects.get_current()` in the view/form when saving a comment!

Comment: That makes sense, although it seems like more work than the other solution provided you do this everytime?  Thanks.